# DRF: Django admin panel with Base Auth and auth on frontend with Simple JWT make response recieve slowly 2x

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt

On my code I have:

JWT:

```
# JWT session

JWT_SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'
JWT_SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = get_env_value(
    'JWT_SESSION_COOKIE_NAME', 'jwt-session'
)
JWT_SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
JWT_SESSION_COOKIE_LIFETIME = timedelta(
    hours=get_env_value('JWT_SESSION_COOKIE_LIFETIME', 1)
)
JWT_SESSION_COOKIE_SAME_SITE = get_env_value(
    'JWT_SESSION_COOKIE_SAME_SITE', 'Lax'
)
JWT_SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = get_env_value(
    'JWT_SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.vidby.com'
)
JWT_SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True



SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(hours=1),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=30),
}
```

And Rest Framework auth settings:

```
# Django REST framework

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_METADATA_CLASS': 'core.metadata.StaffOnlySimpleMetadata',
}
```

When I signin on frontend with JWT and Django Admin Panel in same browser my response recieve 2x slowly

But when I signin on another browser or private window in same browser the problem is being solved

I look in another projects and our codes is identificals settings for auth, and in another project this is not found.